# Let $f$ such that $\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x+\varepsilon y)-f(x)}{\varepsilon}=b+a\cdot y$ $\forall y$. Show that $b=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, gateaux-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{f(x+\varepsilon y)-f(x)}{\varepsilon}=b+a\cdot y$$ $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $b=0$.

I tried this problem, but all that I have untill now is that $$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{f(x+\varepsilon (-y))-f(x)}{\varepsilon}=-\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^-}\dfrac{f(x+\varepsilon y)-f(x)}{\varepsilon}$$

Is about why the Gateaux derivative is of the form $f'(x;y)=a\cdot y$ and not $f'(x;y)=b+a\cdot y$

Comment: I don't understand. $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\varepsilon, y \in \mathbb R$ so what is $x + \varepsilon y$ ?

Comment: $x=(x_1,...,x_n),y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ so $x+\varepsilon y=(x_1+\varepsilon y_1,...,x_n+\varepsilon y_n)$. Are vector operations with $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Ok, so $y \in \mathbb R^n$ !

Comment: yes, sorry I miss that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=0$. Then:

$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon y)-f(x)}{\epsilon}=0=b+ay=b+a0=b$$

Comment: There is a way to show that without $y=0$? because I'm not sure that the directional derivative works with $y=0$ since it has no direction.

Comment: @Jose You said it worked for all $y.$ Therefore it works for $y=0.$

Comment: yes I know, but since $y=0$ has not direction it is strange, so If I put the restriction $y\neq 0$ do you think it still true?